# SQL to LINQ with multiple join, count and left join

Tags: sql, linq, join, left-join, sql-to-linq-conversion

I wrote this SQL request with multiple `JOIN` (including a `LEFT JOIN`).
**It gives me the expected result**.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Id, 
       c.Title, 
       COUNT(v.Id) AS 'Nb_V2',
       COUNT(DISTINCT v.IdUser) AS 'Nb_V1',
       r.cnt AS 'Nb_R'
FROM TABLE_C c
JOIN TABLE_V v on c.Id = v.Id
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT Id, COUNT(*)  AS cnt 
    FROM TABLE_R 
    GROUP BY Id
) r ON c.Id = r.Id
WHERE c.IdUser = '1234'
GROUP BY c.Id, c.Title, r.cnt
```

However, 'Id like the Linq equivalent of this request, to put it my application's Data Access layer.

I tried something like :

```
var qResult = from c in dbContext.TABLE_C
              join v in dbContext.TABLE_V on c.IdC equals v.IdC
              join r in dbContext.TABLE_R on v.IdC equals r.IdC into temp
              from x in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
              group x by new { c.IdC, c.Title /*miss something ?*/} into grouped
              select new
              {
                  IdC = grouped.Key.IdC,          --good result
                  Title = grouped.Key.Title,      --good result
                  NbR = grouped.Distinct().Count(t => t.IdC > 0), --good, but "t.Id > 0" seems weird
                  Count = --I'm lost. No idea how to get my COUNT(...) properties (Nb_V1 and Nb_V2)
              };
```

I tried to adapt [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356439/left-join-in-linq-to-entities) but I can't figure it out. I'm lost with the `Count` inside the groupped sub-request.
Can anyone explain me where i'm wrong ?

Pro tip : Bonus point if someone can write the equivalent with a lambda expression

Comment: The correct answer is - don't. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL, it's a language on top of an ORM. If you need to perform JOINs in LINQ, it means your DbContext lacks the proper relations. Instead of joining you should add the missing relations

Comment: And DbSets aren't tables, they are repositories for entities, with configured relations between each other that generate JOINs dynamically as needed. A DbContext is neither a connection nor a model of the database, it's actually a Unit-of-Work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For translating SQL to LINQ query comprehension:

1. Translate subselects as separately declared variables *unless they reference columns outside the subselect*, in which case use parentheses to create a sub-query.
2. Translate each clause in LINQ clause order, translating single monadic and aggregate operators (`DISTINCT`, `TOP`, `MIN`, `MAX` etc) into functions applied to the whole LINQ query.
3. Use table aliases as range variables. Use column aliases as anonymous type field names.
4. Use anonymous types (`new {` ... `}`) for multiple columns (e.g. in `groupby`).
5. Use `First().field` to get non-key values from the `groupby` aggregate range variable.
6. When using EF or EF Core, translate `JOIN` clauses into navigation properties possibly using `.Include()`.
7. Otherwise `JOIN` clauses that are multiple `AND`ed equality tests between the two tables should be translated into anonymous objects on each side of `equals`.
8. `JOIN` conditions that aren't all equality tests with `AND` must be handled using `where` clauses outside the join, or with cross product (`from` ... `from` ...) and then `where`. If you are doing `LEFT JOIN`, add a lambda `Where` clause between the join range variable and the `DefaultIfEmpty()` call.
9. `LEFT JOIN` is simulated by using `into` *joinvariable* and doing another `from` the *joinvariable* followed by `.DefaultIfEmpty()`.
10. Translate multiple tables in the `FROM` clause into multiple `from` clauses.
11. Translate `FROM T1 CROSS APPLY T2` into two `from` clauses, one for `T1` and one for `T2`.
12. Translate `FROM T1 OUTER APPLY T2` into two `from` clauses, one for `T1` and one for `T2`, but add `.DefaultIfEmpty()` to `T2`.
13. Replace `COALESCE` with the conditional operator (`?:`)and a `null` test.
14. Translate `IN` to `.Contains()` and `NOT IN` to `!`...`Contains()`, using literal arrays or array variables for constant lists.
15. Translate *x* `BETWEEN` *low* `AND` *high* to *low* `<=` *x* `&&` *x* `<=` *high*.
16. Translate `CASE`, `ISNULL` and `IIF` to the ternary conditional operator `?:`.
17. `SELECT *` must be replaced with select range_variable or for joins, an anonymous object containing all the range variables.
18. `SELECT` columns must be replaced with `select new {` ... `}` creating an anonymous object with all the desired fields or expressions.
19. References to computed `SELECT` columns can be translated by repeating the expression or by using `let` to name the expression before its first use.
20. Proper `FULL OUTER JOIN` must be handled with an [extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43669055/2557128).
21. Translate `UNION` to `Concat` unless both sub-queries are `DISTINCT`, in which case you can translate to `Union` and leave off the `DISTINCT`.
22. Translate aggregate queries with multiple result columns that have no `GROUP BY` using a singleton `GroupBy`: add `.GroupBy(r => 1)` (or `group`...`by 1 into g`) and then translate the aggregate functions in the `Select new { }`.
23. Date Math and some other [canonical](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/canonical-functions) functions can be accessed using `EF.Functions` to get an instance of the `DbFunctions` class (EF Core), `EntityFunctions` class (EF < 6) or `DbFunctions` to access the static methods (EntityFramework 6.x).
24. Translate SQL `LIKE` expressions using (EF Core >= 2) `EF.Functions.Like(column, pattern)` or (EF 6.x) `DbFunctions.Like(column, pattern)`.

Applying these rules to your SQL query, you get:

```
var subrq = from r in Table_R
            group r by r.Id into rg
            select new { Id = rg.Key, cnt = rg.Count() };

var ansq = (from c in Table_C
            join v in Table_V on c.Id equals v.Id
            join r in subrq on c.Id equals r.Id into rj
            from r in rj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where c.IdUser == "1234"
            group new { c, v, r } by new { c.Id, c.Title, r.cnt } into cvrg
            select new {
                cvrg.Key.Title,
                Nb_V2 = cvrg.Count(),
                Nb_V1 = cvrg.Select(cvr => cvr.v.IdUser).Distinct().Count(),
                Nb_R = (int?)cvrg.Key.cnt
            }).Distinct();
```

The lambda translation is tricky, but the conversion of `LEFT JOIN` to `GroupJoin`...`SelectMany` is what is needed:

```
var subr2 = Table_R.GroupBy(r => r.Id).Select(rg => new { Id = rg.Key, cnt = rg.Count() });
var ans2 = Table_C.Where(c => c.IdUser == "1234")
                  .Join(Table_V, c => c.Id, v => v.Id, (c, v) => new { c, v })
                  .GroupJoin(subr, cv => cv.c.Id, r => r.Id, (cv, rj) => new { cv.c, cv.v, rj })
                  .SelectMany(cvrj => cvrj.rj.DefaultIfEmpty(), (cvrj, r) => new { cvrj.c, cvrj.v, r })
                  .GroupBy(cvr => new { cvr.c.Id, cvr.c.Title, cvr.r.cnt })
                  .Select(cvrg => new { cvrg.Key.Title, Nb_V2 = cvrg.Count(), Nb_V1 = cvrg.Select(cvr => cvr.v.IdUser).Distinct().Count(), Nb_R = (int?)cvrg.Key.cnt });
```

Comment: It's a nice copy / paste from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48348721/2687153 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/48895078/2687153, but I've already found these posts and I'd appreciate a more personalized answer. Because I'm afraid I'm unable to adapt it to my problem...

Comment: Yeah, I wrote those answers too :) - did you try to apply the recipe?

Comment: I tried your Linq query but I'm stuck at _Fail cast in value type System.Int32, because materialized value is Null. The generic parameter of the result type or the request must use nullable type_ (roughly translated)
Is it because the left join produces some null values ? _subrq_ is good but _ansq_ produces this error. This seem to be the `group new` clause which fails. Could it be the `r.cnt` ?

Comment: The group should translate to SQL and not worry about null, my guess is the final select might be an issue, you could try casting `Nb_R = (int?) cvrg.Key.cnt`

Comment: Brillant ! I was too much focused on the `GroupBy` clause, i didn't see it... I accepted the answer and upvoted it, thanks !
Just for information, in your lambda example, `cvr.r?.cnt` doesn't compile : _An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator_. I tried to force a `int?` cast, even a ternary operator, but same result... That could be a interesting 15th point in your recipe ;-)

Comment: @user2687153 Sorry, that was left over from my testing! I test in LINQPad using LINQ to Objects normally, and it doesn't handle nulls automatically the way LINQ to SQL does so I must put in `?.` but sometimes I forget to take them out when pasting into SO. I fixed it. My guess is the final select might need the same `(int?)` cast in the lambda version.

Comment: It works well. Thank you very much for your help, I deeply appreciate it :)

Comment: It would be good to add a section that strongly advocates using navigation properties instead of joins. This "recipe" may lead to the bad habit of automatically translating joins literally and not leveraging the power of an ORM.

Comment: @GertArnold I added a mention as the first `JOIN` translation.